# I need to show my blob file as a downloadable PDF

Tags: php, sql, pdf, download

Any ideas how? I have done this with and image (getting the image to show but nothing more)

This is what i use for the image:

```
<p style="color:black; font-size:14px; text-align: left">
                    property image here: <br>
                    <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<?php echo base64_encode($mainImage); ?>" />

                    </p>
```

This works brilliantly to show the image on screen. But I have pdf files stored as LONGBLOB's and need to make them downloadable to the users on my site. I need to do this using basic PHP. Any takers?

Answer (score 1):

you should use code looks like :

```
<?php
  header('Content-type: application/pdf');
  header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
  header("Pragma: no-cache");
  header("Content-Disposition: inline;filename='document.pdf'");
  header("Content-length: ".strlen($blob_contents));
  echo $blob_contents;
  exit();
?>
```

Comment: Hi there, i tried this but it doesn't seem to work... my blob file is stored in php as $bigFile. maybe this would help

Comment: u could try if it is file

    $blob_contents = file_get_contents($bigFile);
    header("Content-length: ".strlen($blob_contents));
    echo $blob_contents;

Other wise

    header("Content-length: ".strlen($bigFile));
    echo $$bigFile;

Answer (score 0):

> A word of warning though, storing blobs in databases is generally not
>   considered to be the best idea as it can cause table bloat and has a
>   number of other problems associated with it. A better approach would
>   be to move the file somewhere in the files where it can be retrieved,
>   and store the path to the file in the database instead of the file
>   itself.

it must make heavy your database and would not be easy to take backup of databse

Answer (score 0):

You may create the link with HTML5 "download" attribute that will ask user to download the PDF file like this:

```
<a title="Download PDF" download="Sample.PDF" href="data:application/pdf;base64,%PDFCONTENT%">Click here to download</a>
```